# I can log in, but a page refresh logs me out

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, serverless

I have one project, which I’ll call “Working”, because it works fine, and all login/etc. works fine.

I copied the “serverless.yml” file and changed everything appropriate to start a new project, which I’ll call “Puzzling”.

On the “Puzzling” project, I can log in just fine, but when I refresh the browser, I’m logged out again. So I cannot do things like (e.g.) change a user’s password.

I have all the Cognito configuration in a “config.json” file, with all the right settings.

In fact, if I copy just the “Puzzling” config.json file over to the “Working” project, then the “Working” project stops working properly! So I don’t think it’s my code.

I’ve compared the two “serverless.yml” files carefully… I don’t see anything different.

Any clues VERY MUCH appreciated… Thanks!

Comment: Please share your code so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed: Rebuilt the project by copying from "Working".

POSSIBLY:

- One difference is that "Working" allows users to sign themselves up, and "Puzzling" did not.
- Another thing is that when I went to delete the server code, it failed, saying that the database (or another resource, I forget exactly) was owned by another project.  I deleted that project through the AWS Cloud-formation UI (which only partly worked...).

(And thanks @NewUser, but it's really a lot of code.)